# nth instance of class among siblings different background color using CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to style a list of `div`s with different class names. I want the alternating `div`s with class `item` to be gray and red.

Here's what I'm expecting to see:
[image]

The line that says `nothing` is just there as an example. This list could have any number of `nothing` elements interspersed. I only want to style the `class="item"`s divs with these background colors.

Here's what I thought would work using `nth-of-type`, but didn't:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.item:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: red;
}

.item:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: gray;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="items">
  <div class="item">first</div>
  <div class="not-item">nothing</div>
  <div class="item">second</div>
  <div class="item">third</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried `nth-child`, which also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make this work with `nth-of-type` would be to make the `.not-item` use a different html tag:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.item:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: red;
}

.item:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: gray;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="items">
  <div class="item">first</div>
  <span class="not-item">nothing</span>
  <div class="item">second</div>
  <div class="item">third</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use javascript

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .item {
      background-color: #b4b4b4;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">first</div>
    <div class="not-item">nothing</div>
    <div class="item">second</div>
    <div class="item">third</div>
  </div>

</body>

<script>
  styleDivs = () => {
    let items = document.getElementsByClassName("item")
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (i % 2) {
        items[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000"
      }
    }
  }

  styleDivs()
</script>

</html>
```